# Parsing JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON:

```
var person = {"id": "1", "name": "Michel"}
```

How would I return "1" when "Michel" is selected.

I have tried:

```
for (value in person) {
if (person.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    console.log(value+ " = " + person[value]);
   }
}
```

Comment: please update question and improve clarity

Comment: Underscore / Lodash is a nice framework to use for such things..

Comment: I want the value of first key based on value of second key. means based on michel should return 1.

Comment: woww, nice to see :)

Comment: I suppet that JSON object is inside a array of JSON objects, why don't you loop through it?

Comment: You have a javascript object, you do not have any JSON in the code you posted

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You might as well do `var michel = {"id": "1", "name": "Michel"}; console.log(michel.id);` "selected" only makes sense if you're plucking the object from an array of similar objects based on the name to find its id.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
var person = [{"id": "1", "name": "Michel"}];

for(index=0;index<person.length;index++) {
    if(person[index].name == 'Michel') {
        console.log(person[index].id);
    }
}
```

---

Another Way

```
var person = [{"id": "1", "name": "Michel"}];
var string = 'Michel';

function searchArray(str) {
    var id = '';
    for(index=0; index<person.length; index++) {
        if(person[index].name == str) {
            id = person[index].id;
        }
    }
    return id;
}

var result_id = searchArray(string);
```

Comment: but there's no `return` - and what's to say Michel is "selected"!!

Comment: names are populated in a drop-down, and based on selected name i want to send the id with the name.

Comment: yes get the name when you select something and put it in variable string and then can finish ya ....